# ffmpeg: Can't convert file due to missing pixel format info?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pixelformat

I'm new to ffmpeg and i've been having problems converting this kux file to mp4. I've converted other kux files in the same way before without issues but it seems that this one isn't working because the pixel format is missing from the metadata?

The error message I get is "Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 2991 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options"

The pixel format of other files from the same site is yuv420p so i think that's what it should be.

I tried `ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -i input.kux output.mp4`and some others but it doesnt work. Is there a way around this?

[screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqGLA.jpg)

```
$ ffmpeg -i file.kux output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  3 2015 16:53:06 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --arch=x86 --cross-prefix=/home/builder/mingw-w64-i686-3.6.4/mingw-w64-i686/mingw-w64-i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32- --target-os=mingw32 --pkg-config=pkg-config --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-dxva2 --disable-sse --disable-sse2 --disable-amd3dnow --disable-amd3dnowext --disable-sse3 --disable-ssse3 --disable-sse4 --disable-sse42 --disable-avx --disable-os2threads --disable-ffplay --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --prefix=/home/builder/ffmpeg-i686-mw364-trunk --extra-cflags='-m32 -I/home/builder/mingw-w64-i686-3.6.4/mingw-w64-i686/mingw-w64-i686/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/builder/mingw-w64-i686-3.6.4/mingw-w64-i686/mingw-w64-i686/lib -L/home/builder/mingw-w64-i686-3.6.4/mingw-w64-i686/mingw-w64-i686/bin -static-libgcc -static -lpthread'
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
filename: 2000000004B2C83F5D60CA05DD2DDFF37137ECEA resource name: 03000C3D085EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 71649237 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000006442610A17BBD38CCF0383FC3D62244 resource name: 03000C3D1F5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 71160421 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000093D2A2CAF189D8BDE0CB4C0AF4F33C7 resource name: 03000C3D075EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 87453946 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000011C319DA9AD0274322D7EFCDE3EC6C59 resource name: 03000C3D275EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 86240490 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000013D370CDEE7CB2E9848626F40184D809 resource name: 03000C3D235EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 52428037 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000001601D17A572B08DBF5138FF1CC91E82C resource name: 03000C3D1B5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 93964857 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000001746D4E1E86AF44279495B136214537E resource name: 03000C3D385EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 55809519 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000001D70632B566C624DA74E9BB3EEBE1243 resource name: 03000C3D165EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 60687556 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000002085DD3EB52796B38D7411312EC65C30 resource name: 03000C3D2E5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 55307084 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000245C4B1B016EC6B0A4D5227707597C02 resource name: 03000C3D345EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 56845527 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000002914AEE8CE338B3E48A77FF35656DF7E resource name: 03000C3D015EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 46009465 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000002C2B604DF3A8EEEE50EFC921B4798E89 resource name: 03000C3D365EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 48515489 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000355F348A5408B741616D9B3393B3BC37 resource name: 03000C3D375EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 61953489 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000365CD12351167A229C0F00D7C495926A resource name: 03000C3D3B5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 49107900 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000003868487EDE8CD9C45E33C162CA9FEF8A resource name: 03000C3D305EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 53633177 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000407B5758B1BAB38BC8AED27C3DB41961 resource name: 03000C3D055EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 76786212 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000040BCAF7769169C455AE0E149C7270AFF resource name: 03000C3D0A5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 78011089 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000004A386E61432C47A20D2669E52B84E291 resource name: 03000C3D035EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 60575732 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000004A4C69E330CED6D54D1586BCF938904F resource name: 03000C3D0F5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 76179964 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000050DC27BF2629F1F9BA5B8E0D8C2F9F9F resource name: 03000C3D325EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 67651814 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000005F6A37204661A57EC7F4038427FABBF6 resource name: 03000C3D095EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 89687690 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000060401607278D984DB3607B68138EABB9 resource name: 03000C3D295EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 82789702 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000006368545DB8B2BF68FFD6B0017C949F7A resource name: 03000C3D265EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 79430069 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000065092010658E66602C2AB8D67CC373F5 resource name: 03000C3D115EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 78289056 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000006591CAEDC56BD3003DBD4D77576F97CF resource name: 03000C3D205EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 83948161 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000680E3A53924A5107A43DF96D768A9B3B resource name: 03000C3D065EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 75645190 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000069BFDB1823F81868DDA54248242778EA resource name: 03000C3D1A5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 73292598 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000006D43E4E12E07F9AABDFD4EF37CE58305 resource name: 03000C3D395EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 66663230 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000007360BB392BB6932865BF42588C26BBA9 resource name: 03000C3D315EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 47479418 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000073D0825BC385BAC91312B23FA25A23E0 resource name: 03000C3D0C5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 63807777 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000073D61373D6EEDCAB64B1954AC9B071BB resource name: 03000C3D045EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 72405395 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000007469751F7B42F6C98BD65644F0DA6C51 resource name: 03000C3D3A5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 47683600 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000075CF00F8917F631E017381B0AEC53053 resource name: 03000C3D225EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 58759809 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000007C518AF62853A06400F7D6FCD8B79C53 resource name: 03000C3D0E5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 78550025 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000007F1387496F3FDC9C67DFF18E6160574A resource name: 03000C3D335EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 63382543 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000008B21265B84153D6B3A827741F9BEB343 resource name: 03000C3D285EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 71544982 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000008BB1EF1FAD8D13B3EF30CE27E3B62EA2 resource name: 03000C3D255EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 52285614 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000090ED84F84DDE681EBDC9AA9D01C263FB resource name: 03000C3D2C5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 59365259 embeddment: mp4
filename: 2000000097583623B6A068B074550214113E2C8E resource name: 03000C3D135EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 83450179 embeddment: mp4
filename: 200000009B7CCD3F6ACB89BF304E42461E90202D resource name: 03000C3D245EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 46206057 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000A0025BDCA970792934FBD071883C1925 resource name: 03000C3D2A5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 69956584 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000A545E98754804132C82AA496A99C8B20 resource name: 03000C3D3C5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 84255134 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000AED339260B4E269CC2760D4F2239B57D resource name: 03000C3D0B5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 80414035 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000B709019D0E27EB4A46EA2D73D1B51EEF resource name: 03000C3D185EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 75608939 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000BB2CC4C63C11840491D69166B9AAB300 resource name: 03000C3D145EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 55452492 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000BB33CAA94AAC1909C9F4D8A9B52A6164 resource name: 03000C3D025EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 48171447 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000C18688356E82F47C14BB4826B65BF127 resource name: 03000C3D195EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 78638844 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000C2C573317B8D37F2F23ECA2FDF54E005 resource name: 03000C3D1E5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 81717152 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000C340274C19EBA61C05A85C9598C419E4 resource name: 03000C3D2B5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 84255664 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000C5A837274B8B1C41A7F9784220834121 resource name: 03000C3D1C5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 91022668 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000C65A6C98BD00EE9553F5E1C86F9A1B93 resource name: 03000C3D2F5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 46942287 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000CEEB68B0F38E0427BBEE85B7533F4A4B resource name: 03000C3D005EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 53922663 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000D0DF47CAD069D0671936A222B744EC5A resource name: 03000C3D125EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 81397030 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000D2F6FE60967B100467D683B1F6485B77 resource name: 03000C3D1D5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 91708621 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000D562BFF51185A69354272FDFEC26318F resource name: 03000C3D215EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 83845390 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000D7E90B20BA334E8913C496413D2EF416 resource name: 03000C3D355EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 54393892 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000E9DA5FD06E453016964399326729F90C resource name: 03000C3D2D5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 52357923 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000F0D518178616A424B1A6D7E814125296 resource name: 03000C3D105EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 80636917 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000F83BED20F8046E05FE6C6AC3B1C80791 resource name: 03000C3D0D5EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 68243251 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000F9F9AC094FB5B7CE2AFE6BDADBC6B5A0 resource name: 03000C3D155EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 60286055 embeddment: mp4
filename: 20000000FCB348D712B521FDA966F837E4B4012E resource name: 03000C3D175EC3B60E8BB78000000024A53AEA-6594-486B-BA5C-E1E415CEA17C.mp4 size: 67270979 embeddment: mp4
KUX slices count = 62 pieces_n 61
        0: s 14942208 e 68864871 sz 53922663 em mp4
        1: s 68943872 e 114953337 sz 46009465 em mp4
        2: s 115081216 e 163252663 sz 48171447 em mp4
        3: s 163315712 e 223891444 sz 60575732 em mp4
        4: s 224133120 e 296538515 sz 72405395 em mp4
        5: s 296747008 e 373533220 sz 76786212 em mp4
        6: s 373555200 e 449200390 sz 75645190 em mp4
        7: s 449314816 e 536768762 sz 87453946 em mp4
        8: s 536870912 e 608520149 sz 71649237 em mp4
        9: s 608698368 e 698386058 sz 89687690 em mp4
        10: s 698613760 e 776624849 sz 78011089 em mp4
        11: s 776732672 e 857146707 sz 80414035 em mp4
        12: s 857210880 e 921018657 sz 63807777 em mp4
        13: s 921174016 e 989417267 sz 68243251 em mp4
        14: s 989593600 e 1068143625 sz 78550025 em mp4
        15: s 1068236800 e 1144416764 sz 76179964 em mp4
        16: s 1144520704 e 1225157621 sz 80636917 em mp4
        17: s 1225261056 e 1303550112 sz 78289056 em mp4
        18: s 1303642112 e 1385039142 sz 81397030 em mp4
        19: s 1385168896 e 1468619075 sz 83450179 em mp4
        20: s 1468792832 e 1524245324 sz 55452492 em mp4
        21: s 1524367360 e 1584653415 sz 60286055 em mp4
        22: s 1584660480 e 1645348036 sz 60687556 em mp4
        23: s 1645477888 e 1712748867 sz 67270979 em mp4
        24: s 1712848896 e 1788457835 sz 75608939 em mp4
        25: s 1788608512 e 1867247356 sz 78638844 em mp4
        26: s 1867251712 e 1940544310 sz 73292598 em mp4
        27: s 1940652032 e 2034616889 sz 93964857 em mp4
        28: s 2034761728 e 2125784396 sz 91022668 em mp4
        29: s 2125987840 e 2217696461 sz 91708621 em mp4
        30: s 2217738240 e 2299455392 sz 81717152 em mp4
        31: s 2299527168 e 2370687589 sz 71160421 em mp4
        32: s 2370830336 e 2454778497 sz 83948161 em mp4
        33: s 2454978560 e 2538823950 sz 83845390 em mp4
        34: s 2538864640 e 2597624449 sz 58759809 em mp4
        35: s 2597847040 e 2650275077 sz 52428037 em mp4
        36: s 2650275840 e 2696481897 sz 46206057 em mp4
        37: s 2696675328 e 2748960942 sz 52285614 em mp4
        38: s 2749104128 e 2828534197 sz 79430069 em mp4
        39: s 2828795904 e 2915036394 sz 86240490 em mp4
        40: s 2915041280 e 2986586262 sz 71544982 em mp4
        41: s 2986606592 e 3069396294 sz 82789702 em mp4
        42: s 3069444096 e 3139400680 sz 69956584 em mp4
        43: s 3139436544 e 3223692208 sz 84255664 em mp4
        44: s 3223846912 e 3283212171 sz 59365259 em mp4
        45: s 3283353600 e 3335711523 sz 52357923 em mp4
        46: s 3335782400 e 3391089484 sz 55307084 em mp4
        47: s 3391094784 e 3438037071 sz 46942287 em mp4
        48: s 3438280704 e 3491913881 sz 53633177 em mp4
        49: s 3492020224 e 3539499642 sz 47479418 em mp4
        50: s 3539730432 e 3607382246 sz 67651814 em mp4
        51: s 3607625728 e 3671008271 sz 63382543 em mp4
        52: s 3671064576 e 3727910103 sz 56845527 em mp4
        53: s 3727949824 e 3782343716 sz 54393892 em mp4
        54: s 3782475776 e 3830991265 sz 48515489 em mp4
        55: s 3831234560 e 3893188049 sz 61953489 em mp4
        56: s 3893362688 e 3949172207 sz 55809519 em mp4
        57: s 3949199360 e 4015862590 sz 66663230 em mp4
        58: s 4016046080 e 4063729680 sz 47683600 em mp4
        59: s 4063756288 e 4112864188 sz 49107900 em mp4
        60: s 4113039360 e 4197294494 sz 84255134 em mp4
0: 00:00:00, 138.00
1: 00:02:18, 132.00
2: 00:04:30, 138.00
3: 00:06:48, 132.00
4: 00:09:00, 135.00
5: 00:11:15, 138.00
6: 00:13:33, 132.00
7: 00:15:45, 138.00
8: 00:18:03, 132.00
9: 00:20:15, 138.00
10: 00:22:33, 132.00
11: 00:24:45, 138.00
12: 00:27:03, 132.00
13: 00:29:15, 135.00
14: 00:31:30, 138.00
15: 00:33:48, 132.00
16: 00:36:00, 138.00
17: 00:38:18, 132.00
18: 00:40:30, 138.00
19: 00:42:48, 132.00
20: 00:45:00, 138.00
21: 00:47:18, 132.00
22: 00:49:30, 135.00
23: 00:51:45, 138.00
24: 00:54:03, 132.00
25: 00:56:15, 138.00
26: 00:58:33, 129.36
27: 01:60:42, 140.64
28: 01:63:03, 132.00
29: 01:65:15, 132.00
30: 01:67:27, 138.00
31: 01:69:45, 135.00
32: 01:72:00, 132.00
33: 01:74:12, 138.00
34: 01:76:30, 132.00
35: 01:78:42, 138.00
36: 01:81:00, 132.00
37: 01:83:12, 138.00
38: 01:85:30, 132.00
39: 01:87:42, 138.00
40: 01:90:00, 132.04
41: 01:92:12, 134.96
42: 01:94:27, 138.00
43: 01:96:45, 132.00
44: 01:98:57, 135.92
45: 01:101:12, 134.08
46: 01:103:27, 138.00
47: 01:105:45, 132.00
48: 01:107:57, 135.24
49: 01:110:12, 134.76
50: 01:112:27, 138.00
51: 01:114:45, 132.00
52: 01:116:57, 138.00
53: 01:119:15, 135.00
54: 02:121:30, 132.00
55: 02:123:42, 138.00
56: 02:126:00, 132.00
57: 02:128:12, 132.32
58: 02:130:24, 137.68
59: 02:132:42, 132.00
60: 02:134:54, 183.56
kuxmp4_read_header called  STEP END
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 874812756
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 235394021
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -2050931721
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[aac @ 00ffa630] SBR was found before the first channel element.
[aac @ 00ffa630] Number of scalefactor bands in group (15) exceeds limit (14).
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 530151385
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1268187113
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 132708318
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -325608570
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1213156019
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -534281517
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 295355346
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -371508799
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1531558221
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1138123491
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 660968906
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1410216179
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -204265993
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -781477430
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -7401670
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -866135632
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1152600583
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -198403470
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1183321321
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1661208593
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -2133532789
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -58050872
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 482272599
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1046165719
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 600217459
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 2136677294
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1622472235
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1818050382
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -784861095
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 678945437
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -655091100
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1489853034
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1116378928
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 2094057480
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -85074884
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1642117815
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 2024581390
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1409891885
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -503615064
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1239714289
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 446707089
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -2120649793
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1465654953
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1089282630
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1564850015
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1698565816
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1502839091
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 842445701
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1530672337
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 582504536
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -170295677
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1916524482
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -521256075
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1339137145
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1290441467
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1862593364
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -2133082189
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -237872222
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1178032844
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -780115968
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 839394806
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 580928029
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1391470265
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 126675579
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1556725287
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -24165483
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1946565944
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 278942690
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 597619283
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1879616095
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1133944480
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1654769638
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1133650005
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -135734243
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1727757767
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -804105826
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 913469662
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 819835126
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 712176278
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 878662289
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 814826976
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 2141231623
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1963553054
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1553458215
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 108870028
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 421663844
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 218139476
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1080468970
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 909620780
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1390351749
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 246752082
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1357060696
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1594987762
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1363166934
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1226217672
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -2084315980
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1263286376
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1072213660
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -326146448
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1083678540
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1996866261
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -53829468
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1103737912
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1678455086
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -272434898
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -295475499
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 520379079
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 390397118
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 762903877
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1982610630
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -289761324
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -768506818
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1017388603
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1649544030
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1743810053
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1322170777
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 329648732
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -59919919
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -728972573
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 990133677
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size 1824625322
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[h264 @ 027f0a60] AVC: nal size -1535274491
[h264 @ 027f0a60] no frame!
[kux @ 00ffbfd0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[kux @ 00ffbfd0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 2991 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, kux, from 'file.kux':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : www.aliyun.com - Media Transcoding
  Duration: 02:18:01.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4059 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 2991 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[buffer @ 0344ce90] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0344ce90] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00ff6e30] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Consider increasing the value for the `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` options: `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i input.kux output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan I've already tried that, i get the same message

Comment: Show the full log. Provide a link to `input.kux` if possible.

Comment: @llogan I've added the full log. i can provide a link to the file but it's 4gb....

Comment: Version 2.5 is ancient. Upgrade before trying anything else. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for links to already compiled binaries for Windows, Linux, and macOS.